# TSQL: How to make unique codes in list where dupes appear?

Tags: t-sql, unique

I have the following table:

```
Code Product
==== =======
AA   Prod A
BB   Prod B
CC   Prod C
CC   Prod C1
DD   Prod D
```

I'd like to write a query that takes the CC codes and converts them to CC1 and CC2 respectively and returns that new dataset.

How to do that in T-SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 above

```
DECLARE @code TABLE (Code VARCHAR(20), Product VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @code (Code , Product)
VALUES ('AA','Prod A'),('CC','Prod C'),('CC','Prod C1')

;WITH cc AS 
(
    SELECT Code, COUNT(*) AS CodeCount
    FROM @code
    GROUP BY Code
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN cc.CodeCount = 1 THEN  c.Code
         ELSE c.Code + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY c.Code ORDER BY c.Product) AS VARCHAR(10))  
    END AS Code,
    c.Product
FROM @code c
INNER JOIN cc 
  ON c.Code = cc.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want

```
CC   Prod C
CC1  Prod C1
CC1  Prod C1
CC2  Prod CX
```

You can

```
;with T as (
    select
        code,
        product,
        dense_rank() over (partition by code order by product) as rank
    from 
        thetable
)
select 
    case rank when 1 then code else code + cast(rank - 1 as varchar(8)) end as code,
    product
from
    T
```